# is there any trick or extension tool for play MP4 H.263 format on JwPlayer6?

Tags: mp4, jwplayer, h.263

I know Jwplayer6 can not support from MP4 H.263 format. ([+](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference))
Is there any trick or extension tool for play MP4 H.263 format on JwPlayer6?

Comment: I am not sure if this is supported - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support, however, do you have a link?

Comment: AFAIK, H.263 is considered obsolete - it was introduced almost 20 years ago. Is there some reason you can't convert to H.264?